# Dynamically adding anchor tag

Tags: angular

I'm trying to convert the object to plain html string,

I could successfully convert the object to html, but having challenges to convert the anchor tag.

Below is the object for anchor link ,

```
"multiRangeView":[
   {
      "type":"LINK",
      "data":{
         "target":"_self",
         "url":"/index.htm"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Seems like you're not iterating over `inlineEntityRanges`. So the relevant case is never getting executed.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm not finding login on how to add the `link` inside the `p` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? (Using your stackblitz)

```
private generateHtml(elem: any): string {
  let result ="";
  let inline="";
  result =this.getGenerateHtml(elem);
  if(elem.inlineEntityRanges){
    for(let data of elem.inlineEntityRanges){
      inline =this.getGenerateHtml(data);
         if(inline){
          let text = this.getText(data.offset,data.length,result);
          inline= inline.replace('stringToReplace', text);
          result=result.replace(text,inline);
          }
       }
     }

 return result;
}

getText(offset,length,text:string){
      return text.substr(offset,length);
}

getGenerateHtml(elem: any): string{
   let result ="";
   switch (elem.type) {
   case 'heading-1': result= `<h1>${elem.text.trim()}</h1>`; break;
   case 'paragraph': result = `<p>${elem.text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />").trim()}</p>`; break;
   case 'LINK': result= `<a href='${elem.data.url.trim()}' target=${elem.data.target.trim()}' >stringToReplace</a>`;break;
    }
  return result;
 }
```